# Rails ecommerce site session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, heroku

I have worked through the book Agile Development with Rails 4. I deployed the app using heroku. I only have a login feature for administrators and so anyone can create a cart and submit an order without making an account. I noticed that when i create a cart on my laptop on the deployed website that the cart is the same when i go to my desktop. So there is one cart with say id = 20 shared among all sessions. This is obviously a problem. I suspect it has to do with my module for current_cart but not sure.

```
module CurrentCart 
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    private
      def set_cart 
        @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id]) 
      rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
        @cart = Cart.create 
        session[:cart_id] = @cart.id    
      end
end
```

I then use include CurrentCart and before_action:set_cart on the store, orders, line items, and carts controllers. I would like each session to be associated with each computer and end upon closing the browser, which I know can vary with the browser settings. I believe this might also be happening because I am storing this information in the database so the cart_id persists until the cart is deleted. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It was due to caching in production. I changed     config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
and it works now.